# Create file to Root of S3 Bucket in AWS using Lambda

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am working with a script where I automatically run elastic transcoder on a file uploaded. Then it will export the encoded version to another S3 bucket.

However it is writing to a folder. This creates a problem for me because technically the folders do not exist and so there is no record of the creation date.

This makes it hard for me to manage the creation date of files as we can only see the modification date of the "folder" which is blank. Is it possible to make my files upload to the root of the bucket and therefore without being inside of a folder?

I feel like it has something to do with this: OutputKeyPrefix: newKey + '/',
However I have tried removing it, and setting it to '', without any success

```
exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    console.log('Executing Elastic Transcoder');

    var bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    var key = event.Records[0].s3.object.key;
    var pipelineId = '1521208528859-x';

    console.log(key);
    console.log(event.Records[0]);

    if (bucket !== 'video-upload') {
        context.fail('Incorrect Video Input Bucket');
        return;
    }

    var srcKey = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\-/g, " ")); //the object may have spaces  
    var newKey = key.split('.')[0];

    var params = {
        PipelineId: pipelineId,
        OutputKeyPrefix: newKey + '/',
        Input: {
            Key: srcKey,
            FrameRate: 'auto',
            Resolution: 'auto',
            AspectRatio: 'auto',
            Interlaced: 'auto',
            Container: 'auto'
        },
        Outputs: [{
            Key: newKey + '.mp4',
            ThumbnailPattern: 'thumbs-' + newKey + '-{resolution}' + '-{count}',
            PresetId: '1351620000001-000010', //Generic 720p
            Watermarks: [{
                InputKey: 'watermarks/logo-dark.png',
                PresetWatermarkId: 'BottomRight'
            }],
        }]
    };

    console.log('Starting Job');

    eltr.createJob(params, function(err, data){
        if (err){
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log(data);
        }

        context.succeed('Job well done');
    });
};
```

Comment: I guess OutputKeyPrefix is optional, you add it it should add prefix to file "OutputKeyPrefix/filename.mp4" else not. can you try just removing it?

Comment: I tried removing this, still adds it to the folder :/

Comment: If you pass **any** slashes (`/`) then the object will appear to be inside a folder.  This would include the one you are adding at `OutputKeyPrefix: newKey + '/'` as well as any others that are already in `newKey`.  If you are confident that you are passing none at all, please show a specific example of input values and output results.